# CIFS mount in /etc/fstab works in 14.04 but not 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mount, samba, fstab

I'm provisioning a 16.04 server to replace a 14.04 server and running into an oddity mounting CIFS drives via /etc/fstab. This is my fstab entry on both machines:

```
//192.168.0.10/share    /mnt/share    cifs    username=myuser,noauto 0 0
```

On 14.04 if I type "sudo mount /mnt/share" I'm prompted for the samba account password and the mount succeeds. Typing the same command on 16.04 I get this instead:

```
mount: //192.168.0.10/share is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: cannot mount //192.168.0.10/share read-only
```

And if I look in syslog I see this:

```
Apr  6 10:13:37 localhost kernel: [63103.182822] Status code returned 0xc000006d NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
Apr  6 10:13:37 localhost kernel: [63103.182829] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
Apr  6 10:13:37 localhost kernel: [63103.183097] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
Apr  6 10:13:37 localhost kernel: [63103.191019] Status code returned 0xc000006d NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
Apr  6 10:13:37 localhost kernel: [63103.191026] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
Apr  6 10:13:37 localhost kernel: [63103.191285] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

The 16.04 system does not prompt me for the samba account password and then, of course, authentication fails. Furthermore if I put the password into the /etc/fstab entry on the 16.04 server then the mount succeeds. It seems like the crux of the problem is 16.04 no longer prompts for a password; how do I get that functionality back?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is because cifs-utils wasn't installed. It's unclear to me why mounting a cifs drive worked fine without this package so long as the password was in /etc/fstab, but after installing it I get a proper password prompt.